# Google Cloud App Deploy and Cloud SQL Schema migrations

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I wonder if I should handle schema updates when deploying new code with gcloud app deploy. Should I just go in manually and update the tables in the database, and then run a deploy? Or is there some way I can have SQL files that need to be applied on a deploy?